# How can I prevent Grails finder methods saving my objects?

Tags: hibernate, grails, transactions, grails-orm, spring-transactions

I'm having a Grails 2.4.4 controller:

```
class FooController {
    def fooService

    @Transactional
    def save(Foo foo) {
         def duplicateFoos = fooService.duplicateFoos(foo)
         if (duplicateFoos) {
              flash.error = "Duplicate foos exist: $duplicateFoos"
              render(model: foo, view: 'create')
         } else { /* ... */ }
    }
```

The service is also quite simple

```
@Transactional
class FooService {
    def duplicateFoos(Foo foo) {
        log.info(foo) // here foo has no ID
        JobAssignment.findAllBySomeProperty(foo.someProperty)
        log.info(foo) // here new ID is assigned to foo
    }
}
```

The Foo arrives unsaved and without an ID into the duplicateFoos method but after it executes it is suddenly with an ID and saved in the database (as seen from the log statements).

I have

```
dataSource {
    flush.mode = 'manual'
}
```

in `DataSource.groovy`.

I tried manually

```
sessionFactory.currentSession.transaction.rollback()
```

or

```
sessionFactory.currentSession.transaction.rollback()        
sessionFactory.currentSession.transaction.begin()
```

in `FooController`. In this case, ID still gets assigned at the `findAllBySomeProperty` stage (not sure why), but it doesn't get persisted to the database. However, I'm getting `org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started`.

I also tried manually setting `sessionFactory.currentSession.flushMode = FlushMode.MANUAL` and while it seemed to help in this one particular spot (no new ID assigned), other later code which didn't call `save` on that (or any) object still saved it. I also don't think sprinkling `flushMode = MANUAL` at start of every transactional method is a good solution.

I have now resorted to just throwing an `Exception` - which ensures nothing is saved. This is obviously not a good solution, as I need to redirect back to the form instead.

So how can I force objects to only be saved when I call `.save`?

Alternatively, if that is not possible, how do I cleanly roll back the transaction while still being able to redirect to some screen?

P.S. There are a bunch of possibly related Grails JIRAs that I reviewed, but I didn't find a solution to my troubles in them:

- https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11701
- https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11536
- https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11687
- https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11797

---

@BurtBeckwith, yes, Foo `belongsTo` Bar, and Bar `hasMany` Foo-s (both are standard Grails domain objects).

However, I don't operate the Bar-s in these methods. All I do is a:

```
def createForBar(Long barId) {
    Bar bar = Bar.findById(barId)
    Foo foo = new Foo(bar: bar)
    render(view: 'create', model: createModel(foo))
}
```

And then the `create` form has a button which invokes the aforementioned `save`.

---

@JeffScottBrown - it is a `POST`, there is no `id` parameter when creating a new `Foo`.

I'm passing a

```
<input type="hidden" name="bar.id" value="${fooInstance?.bar?.id}"/>
```

though.

Comment: Is the `Foo` instance part of another domain class collection? It's very rare that a new instance would magically become saved - the only ways are transitive saving, e.g. this Foo is in a Bar instance's `foos: Foo` collection, and since the `Bar` is modified/dirty (by adding foo), it's persisted during the flush, and the `Foo` instance is transitively saved. But without some sort of belongsTo/ownership relationship, pretty much the only way to make a new unsaved instance persistent is to explicitly call `save()` on it.

Comment: As written, what is described there does not make any sense to me.  There must be something missing from the description that explains that behavior.  What type of request method is being used, is there an "id" request parameter and if so, does its value correspond to a record in the datastore?

Comment: Thanks - responded in question text to both comments.